# Strange issue with curl and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

Hello I have a really strange bug.
 I have two pages the first one has a form, a very simple form with only one input field and a button, only for typing numbers

This page loads the response using ajax, but here is the issue, the php file that process the information is in another domain, as we all know cross-domain ajax is not posible

The idea that I got in order to make this work was the following: The target PHP is a simple cURL request that receives the "POST" data and then throug cURL it loads the information from the PHP file from the other domain.

Each file is located in diferents servers (The form and the curl php, in one server, and the actual php procesing page in the other server)

Both are accesible from internet, if I test fuctionality of both on a local wamp server it works perfectly, after I upload each part to the corresponding server if I test them indidividually they both work, but when I try the actual thing they don't seem to be able to comunicate with each other and I don't know why

if I try "curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);" I get "0"
 and "curl_error($curl)" I get: Failed to connect to "The url" : Connection timed out

I wonder if this is a security issue, the server that has php processing page is a windows server 2008 R2 with wampserver

The server that has the form and the cURL, is from a hosting service that I bought

Here the source code:
The form with the ajax request:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')
?>
<div>
<p>
Introduzca el número de orden que aparece en ticket 
</p>

<p>

<input type="number" id="ordenNum" onkeyup="verificar(event);" />
<input type="button" value="Verifificar" disabled  onclick="cargar();" 
id="boton" />

</p>
</div>

<div id="respuesta">

</div>
<script>
var respuesta = document.getElementById("respuesta");
var campoOrden = document.getElementById("ordenNum");
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

function cargar(){
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        respuesta.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } else if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404){
        respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Hubo un problema con nuestro servidor 
principal, por favor intente mas tarde</p>";
    } else {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "anim2.gif";
        respuesta.appendChild(img);
    }
}
ajax.open("POST", "procesar.php", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send("orden="+campoOrden.value);
}

function verificar(event){
var longitud = campoOrden.value;
var enter = event.keyCode;
if(enter == 13){
    boton.click();
}
if(longitud.length > 0){
    boton.removeAttribute("disabled");
} else {
    boton.setAttribute("disabled", "");
}
}
</script>
```

The cURL page :

```
$curl = curl_init("the url from the other server");
$post = array("orden" => $_POST['orden']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: What does `curl_error($curl)` give you?

Comment: @GentlemanMax Failed to connect to "the url of the second server": Connection timed out

Comment: That usually means that the server you are connecting to is unreachable by the server you are sending from.  The obvious things to check: Are you connecting by IP address or hostname, if you are going by hostname, is the sending server able to resolve the address of the receiving server?  Does the firewall on the receiving server allow the sending server to access it?

Comment: It is connecting through a hostname, but I also tried an Ip address as a test purpose, and it didn't work neither, the receiving server is a Windows server 2008 R2 and I just checked the firewall and is disabled, I don't know if there is an other security policy that I should edit, but it is weird because if try to acces the web page directly, on this server, from the internet (outside its LAN) it works, it is like rejecting the incoming curl requests